# Collapse / Expand accordion menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a accordion style tab on this page https://www.hawaiidiscount.com/oahu/luaus/germaines.htm

When I test this offline it works but not on DNN.
See where it says Video. This should collapse the tab when you click on it. And when you see it with a small device it is collapsed by default and it should expand when you click it. 
My js code is:

```
// Includes Everything
$(document).ready(function() {
    // level 1

    $(".arrow-right").hide();

    $(".LuauPackages").on("mouseover", function() {
        // Mouse Pointer
        $(".LuauPackages").css( { cursor: "pointer" } );

    });


    $(".LuauPackages").on("click", function() {
        if( $(this).parent().find(".LuauPackCont").is(":visible") ) {
            $(this).parent().find(".LuauPackCont").slideUp("fast");
            $(this).parent().find(".arrow").removeClass("arrow-down").addClass("arrow-right");
            } else {
            $(this).parent().find(".LuauPackCont").slideDown("fast");
            $(this).parent().find(".arrow").removeClass("arrow-right").addClass("arrow-down");
        }
    });


    // this is if window is greater than or equal to 736px
    if( $(window).width() <= 736 ) {
        $(".LuauPackCont").hide();
        $(".arrow-right").show();
        $(".arrow-down").hide();
    }
});
```

I would appreciate any tips what might be wrong.
Thanks!

UPDATE: The code works fine when it is inline but when I put it in external scripts file it doen't work.

Comment: your hiding and showing should be handled with media queries in your CSS. your hover states (`cursor: pointer;`) should be handled by CSS too

Comment: Console says `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).colorbox is not a function`. This breaks your code right after `$(document).ready`.

Comment: Can you show how you are including the external scripts file?

Comment: @Tony well, just visit the site and inspect the code. There are many  (many.......) JS files included.

Comment: @JeremyThille I guess that's the point. People probably won't go digging trying to find which file includes the code above and if it's relevant to the answer, then it would be helpful for future visitors.

Comment: @Parlanchina Were you able to get this code working? If so, what was the issue?

Answer (score 2):

I can't comment as I don't have enough reputation but I noticed that you use $(this) alot. Just a tip, it's cleaner and more efficient to store the object in a variable once and then use that instead. Every time you use $(this) it is a function to create a new JQuery object. I have amended part of your code below to reflect this. I hope this helps.

```
$(".LuauPackages").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this).parent(); // Caches JQuery object

    if( $this.find(".LuauPackCont").is(":visible") ) {
          $this.find(".LuauPackCont").slideUp("fast");
          $this.find(".arrow").removeClass("arrow-down").addClass("arrow-right");
        } else {
          $this.find(".LuauPackCont").slideDown("fast");
          $this.find(".arrow").removeClass("arrow-right").addClass("arrow-down");
    }
});
```

Comment: Why stop with `$(this)`? Cache `$(this).parent()`, that will optimize the code even more. And even `$this.parent().find(".LuauPackCont")`, that is being called three times.

Comment: You should have renamed `$this` to `$parent`, because it's not `this` anymore but its parent... Gets complicated hmm? :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to change the order of your `<script>` tags. If there are references to jQuery or jQuery-UI before it's loaded, you'll get an error. Try ordering the `<script>` tags like so:

1. jQuery
2. jQuery-UI
3. You JavaScript files

Here's what I see on your site:

```
<script src="/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/Nav/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/Nav/mobile-menu.js"></script>
<script src="/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/js/contentslider.js"></script>
<script src="/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/js/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script src="/Portals/0/Skins/HD-custom-design-s/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

It looks like there are jQuery and jQuery-UI files loaded after your JS files.

In Chrome devtools, I see your site is showing this error (as Jeremy pointed out):

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).colorbox is not a function

You might be running into the same issue as this post:

[JQuery and Colorbox loaded but "colorbox is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828916/jquery-and-colorbox-loaded-but-colorbox-is-not-a-function)