# Conflicting ubergallery and custom script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `ubergallery` for a picture gallery and I copied a script for a pop-up form, which I turned into a contact-us form pop-up.

When I use both scripts, my `ubergallery` doesn't work. Is there a way for both scripts to work together?

the script are in the correct order, according to the instructions i followed. I just don't know which one to delete/alter in order for both functions to work.

```
    <!-- script/css for ubergallery -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/resources/UberGallery.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/resources/colorbox/1/colorbox.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/resources/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="resources/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("a[rel='Images 1']").colorbox({maxWidth: "90%", maxHeight: "90%", opacity: ".5"});
          $("a[rel='Images 2']").colorbox({maxWidth: "90%", maxHeight: "90%", opacity: ".5"});
          $("a[rel='Images 3']").colorbox({maxWidth: "90%", maxHeight: "90%", opacity: ".5"});
        $("a[rel='Images 4']").colorbox({maxWidth: "90%", maxHeight: "90%", opacity: ".5"});
        $("a[rel='Images 5']").colorbox({maxWidth: "90%", maxHeight: "90%", opacity: ".5"});
        $("a[rel='Images 6']").colorbox({maxWidth: "90%", maxHeight: "90%", opacity: ".5"});
      });
         </script>

    <!--script/css for pop-up form-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
```

This is the error that I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).colorbox is not a function at
>   HTMLDocument. (##.php:24) at j (jquery.js:2) at
>   Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2) at Function.ready
>   (jquery.js:2) at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:2)

Comment: What errors are you getting in the browser console? Why are you including jQuery twice, and two different versions at that?

Comment: Do you have multiple document.ready functions among those scripts?

Comment: sorry, i'm new to php. i just put together different scripts i find.

Comment: the error i get:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).colorbox is not a function
            at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (##.php:24)
            at j (jquery.js:2)
            at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
            at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
            at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.js:2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery and Colorbox loaded but "colorbox is not a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828916/jquery-and-colorbox-loaded-but-colorbox-is-not-a-function)

Comment: I literally just searched your error on google to find that question I posted above, maybe you should do that too next time before rushing to ask a question that's already been answered :)

Comment: The script tags appear to be in the correct order, at least in the first part of the code sample above -- but there are duplicates of both jquery and colorbox.js (loaded from multiple different URLs) that may be causing the issue.  (Even if it *isn't* causing the issue, it's a waste of bandwidth to link two copies of the same library...)

Comment: The error is from the fact there is two versions of jQuery loaded which was mentioned 25 mins ago.

Comment: but which one should i delete? and would it affect my gallery and pop-up form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery library and colorbox plugin were loaded twice. That is never good.

Below are the [CDNs](https://cdnjs.com/) for them. They will work.
Now you will have to check if your relative path CSS files are correct *(not 404 not found, [check the **console**](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers))* and loaded in the right order... I just can't tell you this.

Also... I pretty sure that you cannot use a space in the `rel` attribute. I removed it from the selectors... Also remove it from your HTML markup.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/resources/UberGallery.css" /> <!-- Check this one -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/resources/colorbox/1/colorbox.css" /> <!-- Check this one -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/demos/style.css"> <!-- Check this one -->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.colorbox/1.6.4/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel='Images1']").colorbox({maxWidth: "90%", maxHeight: "90%", opacity: ".5"});
    $("a[rel='Images2']").colorbox({maxWidth: "90%", maxHeight: "90%", opacity: ".5"});
    $("a[rel='Images3']").colorbox({maxWidth: "90%", maxHeight: "90%", opacity: ".5"});
    $("a[rel='Images4']").colorbox({maxWidth: "90%", maxHeight: "90%", opacity: ".5"});
    $("a[rel='Images5']").colorbox({maxWidth: "90%", maxHeight: "90%", opacity: ".5"});
    $("a[rel='Images6']").colorbox({maxWidth: "90%", maxHeight: "90%", opacity: ".5"});
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Louys! that worked! now i understand what they meant with the order. :)

Comment: Yes... The order. For `.js` files, that is a matter of loading the dependencies first. For the `.css` files, that is about one rule having the same selector as another one being overruled by the second. The last will be used. That is why this is called CSS "Cascading Style Sheet".